# $.each in success of AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, each

I want to request something with AJAX (no problem), I'll get plain html back which looks like this

```
<div> abc </div>
<div> def </div>
```

now I want to do `$.each` through the html elements received in the success part of AJAX.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#someButton").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Cens/ored',
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function (data) {

            }
        });

    });
});
```

How can I do this?

Comment: So you didn't try anything? even the obvious `$(data).each(`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well that depends, if you need to append only the plain html in some part of your dome you could do something like this

```
$('your Selector').append(data) without any each at all in the success callback,
```

Now, if you need to attach each div that you're receiving in different's parts of the Dom, you should take use the each function like this, note's that is just a example

```
$(data).find('div').each(function(){
    alert($(this).html());
});
```

Comment: oh man.. its so easy... Thanks, but another question cause i wasnt specific enough in my first post, the data is something like this <div id="test"> <div></div><div></div> </div><div id="test"> <div></div><div></div> </div> so i only want the tests, $(data).find('#test').each(function(){
    alert($(this).html());
}); dont work

Comment: i changed from id to class and sorrounded the div with another div, now its working. dunno why he keeps ignoring the outer div

Answer (score 3):

You could do it with `$(data).each(...`.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#someButton").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Cens/ored',
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function (data) {
　　　　　　　　$(data).each(function(index, el) {
                  //....
               });
            }
        });

    });
});
```